# How to pass a dynamic parameter in option in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, pug

I use Jade with my Meteor.

I want to pass a dynamic parameter to a function using the option keyword,
but I get the following error:

play.jade: Jade syntax error: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, null, or a sub expression enclosed in "(", ")"
{{.}}

See my code below, myInput function returns arbitrary values which are the values for the list box, and the testing function should print the chosen value.

In play.jade:

```html
select(id="input"
name="select"
value="a"
style="border-right-color: #c0c0c0 !important;"
type="text")
  each myInput
    <option {{testing #{.}}}>#{.}</option>
```

In play.js:

```js
myInput = function() {
    var myArray = ["ABC", "123", "DEF"];
    return myArray;
};

testing: function(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this? ```<option {{testing #{.}}}>#{.}</option>``` I have a feeling it's unable to resolve the other handlebars within ```<option {{  }} >```

Comment: {{testing}} is the helper function I want to invoke when clicking the list box. #{.} is the value passed from the each statement in every interaction, I use it as parameter to the testing function. It works well if I only write <option {{testing}}>#{.}</option> or {{testing "parameter"}}>#{.}</option>

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this to the function and this will be your values from the array.

```
In play.jade:

select(id="input"
name="select"
value="a"
style="border-right-color: #c0c0c0 !important;"
type="text")
  each myInput
    <option +testing(this)>+this</option>
```